# Idle message when logged in to control panel

Tags: control-panel, login

I get this message at the bottom of the page of the control panel:
"You've gone idle, please enter your password to continue."

[image: Idle message]

I just updated to ExpressionEngine to 2.7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that looks like a JS conflict with a cp add-on like Devot:EE monitor or a straight out EE theme error. Presumably on a new entry screen you'll see the file manager modal down there too.

Try replacing/re-uploading the themes folder for EE, updating the accessories to latest (or any extensions which modify the CP JS), then clear your browser cache.

Comment: Give clearing your browser cache a whirl before doing the rest of the items suggested here; either way, this is a good answer, I think.

Comment: Thanks Iain I replaced the ExpressionEngine files and that did the trick!